# How do I convert a delimited string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I tried to convert this string literal into dictionary object in python without success:

```
args = 'key_1=895, key_2=f.Comment'
args = args.replace("'","")
args = dict(args)
```

But I got an error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I knew that my `args` is still one string as `.replace()` that I tried to remove single quote did not work. How ? Please kindly help me converting to dictionary object, I just want it as a result: `{'key_1':895,'key_2':'f.Comment'}`. Thanks

Comment: There are no single quotes in that string. Single quotes were only used to mark the beginning and end of a string literal; they are not part of the string itself.

Comment: @Selcuk, Ah, Understand, but as this `args = 'key_1=895, key_2=f.Comment'` how to I convert it to dict? I know the correct type would be `dict(key_1=895,key2="f.Comment")`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no single quotes in that string. Single quotes were only used to mark the beginning and end of a string literal; they are not part of the string itself.

To parse the string into a dictionary you can use the `.split()` method and a generator expression:

```
>>> dict(part.strip().split("=") for part in args.split(","))
{'key_1': '895', 'key_2': 'f.Comment'}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks very much. Additionally, thanks for your kindness to upvote and edit question and question title to be fitted, it's looking quite awesome :)

Comment: All good, I'm glad it worked for you. Note that this will interpret all values as strings (e.g. `"895"`) and not numbers as one might expect. You will need to implement extra logic if you need that.

Comment: I noted that, thanks so much for your help.